# Does it "save memory" to put methods in one Big class? (Many objects)

Tags: c#, xna

I'm working on a game for moblie platforms where memory is always a concern.

I'm using a base abstract class enemy.  All other enemies will be variants of this class.

My initial intent is to store methods for updating the enemy in the base class, and then store the specific behaviors in each child enemy class.

My question is this: With possibly hundreds of enemies per load (or level), will I save memory writing all of my behaviors in one big class which each enemy refers to?  In other words, does having hundreds of enemies, each of which has a boatload of behaior code, require much more memory than storing everything in a single reference class?

Initial Idea:

```
enemy.Update()
```

Memory saving idea:

```
//Static class is named EnemyBehavior
EnemyBehavior.UpdateEnemy(enemy)
```

Comment: Code isn't stored in a class. Classes only store data.

Comment: I think you mean *instance*, @David.

Comment: Classes store data in their instances, yes. But they don't store code anywhere at all.

Comment: I can see how classes might be said to store data, @David, but not in a sense that's useful for the OP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although each instance of your class has its own private, memory-consuming copies of its variables, it does **not** have separate copies of its method definitions. Methods consume memory per-*class*, not per-*instance*. That only makes sense, since it's not possible for a class instance to change the definition of a method. So, sorry, but your idea won't save any memory.

Comment: That's what I was hoping to hear.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

That's not quite how memory works. The heap will need to store *data* and references, not *actual code*. As such, you don't save anything by deciding where to store 'common code' in a static class - having the code with your object instances doesn't mean it is physically copied into every instance.

What you're suggesting goes against the whole reason for object oriented programming, which is encapsulation of behaviour and separation of concerns.

tl;dr - keep the code with the class itself.

Comment: Well, the Types are stored "on the heap", but just once per type in a manner than can be largely ignored ;-)

Comment: It's worth noting that not all languages work this way.  Some more dynamic languages, such as some scripting languages, don't define class methods in a class definition, but rather have essentially treat all methods as delegates.